# every vs. any in statements

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

*There doesn’t have to be an answer to every question.*

*There doesn’t have to be an answer to any question.*

Is there any difference between the first sentence and the second sentence?

Comment: Usually in such contexts, ***every** question* means ***all** questions, **without exception***, but ***any** question* means ***one** (randomly selected) question*. Because of the negation of ***doesn’t have to be,*** the default interpretation of your first text is that it's okay for *some* questions not to have answers, whereas the second version implies it's okay for *none* of the questions to have answers.

Comment: Let's think there are ten questions. As to these questions, if there doesn’t have to be an answer to every question, then, for example, it is O.K. for one question to have no answer or have answers more than one and for the other nine questions to have one answer each. Here, under the same condition, is it also O.K. for all of the ten questions to have no answer each?

Comment: Like I said, your *second* version would normally be understood to mean it's okay for *none* of the questions to have answers. But no-one would ever say the first version with that meaning. Also note that ***an** answer* doesn't remotely imply it would be possible for a question to have *multiple* answers. In that case, at the very least you'd have to use "emphatic" ***one** answer* - but it would be such an unlikely / unusual situation you'd probably have to use a lot more words to be certain of being understood.

Comment: Many thanks for your helpful reply.